# Just like superclass members, do superclass constructors form part of the subclass object state?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, nested, subclass

Please allow me to explain my understanding.

```
class P
{
    P()
    {
        System.out.println("hi "+this); 
       /*which object of P is currently executing this constructor? 
         Is "this" here object referenced by q or some other object?*/
    }
}
class Q extends P
{
    Q()
    {
        super();  
        /*constructor of superclass called on this object(referenced by q) */
    }
}
class R
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Q q = new Q(); //constructor Q() invoked on object referenced by q
    }
}
```

So my doubts are:
1. super() is invoked on which object of P(since none exists).
2. What is "this" in P() referring to? Is it the same object as q? In other words is this=q ?

Comment: If you are asking if `super()` calls `super()` of its own superclass then the answer is yes (until superclass is `Object`).

Comment: I have edited my question. Please recheck

Comment: Two days ago, you asked a very very similar question.  You insisted over and over that there was no instance of `P` (except you called it `A` when you asked the question before).  I, and others, explained that there WAS an instance of `P` because any instance of `Q` is also an instance of `P`.  Why are you still insisting that there's no instance of `P`?  Do you not read the answers and comments after  you ask a question?

Comment: that means polymorphism is at work here...since we are able to access superclass constructor using subclass reference(which ofcourse is superclass reference too)?

Answer (score 3):

Code, ctors included, does not define 'object state'. Set of instance fields do. And, under the hood, subclass instances *do* include `private` fields of their superclasses, but `javac` makes sure that they only accessible, directly or indirectly, by calling superclass methods (ctors included).

---

Regarding your updated question:

```
class Q extends P
{
    Q()
    {
        super();  /*constructor of superclass called on this object(referenced by q) */
    }
}
```

Here Q extends P, so `super()` calls P's ctor. During execution of P's ctor, `this` allows to refer to fields and methods belonging to P and to it's supertypes (e.g., `Object`) w/ restrictions imposed by access modifiers (I mean you can access only `public` and, w/ restrictions `protected` and 'package-private' members of subtypes), **but not to P's subtypes**.

Regarding "no access to P's subtypes" rule there's one more twist: if you call some non-private (overridable) method of P from P's ctor, chances are this method will be overridden someday in `Q` or other subtype, and you suddenly start calling some unforeseen code! So, `this` inside `P` does allow to refer explicitly to P's subtype methods but not to P's subtype fields (although implicitly P's fields can be reached by P's subtype method).

To give an example -- change `f()` in following code from `private` to 'package-local' and witness a NPE thanks to following execution chain `Derived#Derived() -> Base#Base() -> Derived#f() -> NPE!`:

```
class Base {

    private Integer base = 1;

    Base() {
        f();
    }

    private void f() {
        System.out.println(base);
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {

    private Integer derived;

    Derived() {
        super();
        derived = 2;
        f();
    }

    private void f() {
        System.out.println(derived.intValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are not inherited to subclasses. And using `super()` you can just call the super class constructor. You can not access the private variable/property of super class from subclass. Moreover private member of a super class is also not inherited to it's subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are not inherited in java.

As per the [official Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html):

> A subclass inherits all the members (fields, methods, and nested
>   classes) from its superclass. Constructors are not members, so they
>   are not inherited by subclasses, but the constructor of the superclass
>   can be invoked from the subclass.

When you call `super()` you simply invoke the parent constructor, which *can* access private members of the class it belongs to.

As for the updated version of your question:

1. As mentioned above, `super()` simply invokes the parent constructor. It's not invoked on any object, since constructor is not a member of a class.
2. `this` in the `P` constructor will refer to the instance of a subclass (`Q`) that is being constructed.

**EDIT:**
Regarding 2. This can be easily verified by outputting the reference `q` in your `main` method. It should print exactly the same that the `System.out.println(this)` call in the `P` constructor.

```
public class R
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Q q = new Q(); //constructor Q() invoked on object referenced by q
        System.out.println(q);
    }
}
```

Comment: you mentioned super() can access private instance members. But instance members are always associated with objects. So when we are accessing an instance member from a constructor which object's instance member are we accessing?

Comment: @user3678484 It's not super() that's accessing private instance members - it's the parent constructor. Nevertheless, if you invoke a virtual (and non private) method from within the constructor - the call will be polymorphic. Since private methods do not get inherited, a call to a private method will simply invoke the method from the class that defines the constructor. Hope that makes sense...